# Browser-based app framework for Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, user-interface, frameworks, sinatra

I've a ruby script running out of the command line. I want to provide a local GUI for it (for my use). As I have some exposure to Sinatra and other web frameworks, I want to use HTML pages as my front-end. But I don't want to start a server and type in a URL every time I want to launch my app.

My solution would be to write a shell script which will start a Sinatra based server and then launch Chromium(Browser) in app mode to that url.

Is there some framework which can do it better/cleaner?

I'm not interested in learning a non-HTML framework like Shoes or Ruby-Gnome2.

Comment: Found [Bowline](http://bowlineapp.com) just now and it seems to fit my description. I'll update after checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
ruby $1 &
chromium localhost:4567
```

Put that somewhere in your `$PATH` (or change it to contain `$HOME/bin` with `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` and put it there), make it executable with `chmod +x <file>` and have fun by calling `<file> <sinatra startup file>`

You could extend this to read the port from Sinatra, but that would require a ruby startup, and this should do in most of the cases (the 80%, as people call it).

Comment: Sorry! What I meant was that, "Is there some framework which can render HTML views instead of me writing that shell script?"

Comment: Is there a way to kill the `ruby $1 &` command when I quit the browser?